# treeitem icon doesn't show

Tags: java, treeview, javafx-2

I'm working with treeview in javaFx, I want to put an icon to the root node, and other icon for every child. I was trying to put it at least to the root node, but it still shows me the arrow, I declare the node in the next way:

```
TreeItem<Object> rootNode = new TreeItem<Object>("Agentes");
rootNode.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/A.png"))));
```

I have the image "A.png" in a package called *application.images*

, and my loader class is Main.java is located in *application*, this is my directory:
[image]

when I run the application this is the treeview that I get:

[image]

it doesn't show me error or something like this. I must say, A.png is a image with 16x16Pixels. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it, putting `setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/A.png"))));` into the `updateItem( Object item, boolean empty )`  method in the a class that extends from TreeCell